# Excel "found unreadable content" error opening a xlsx created from C#

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

I'm creating an Excel file (xlsx) from C# using OpenXML.

When I create a xlsx file and I open, it has no error.

When I try to attach that file on an e-mail and send it, Excel returns the message "found unreadable content" opening the attached file, with Yes/No button to continue.

Clicking on Yes the file is opened correctly.

This is my code to attach an xlsx file:

```
byte[] bt = functionToCreateXlsxfile();

MailMessage message = new MailMessage();

System.Net.Mail.Attachment attach = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(
        new MemoryStream(bt),
        "myfile.xlsx", 
        "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");

attach.ContentDisposition.CreationDate = DateTime.Now;
attach.ContentDisposition.ModificationDate = DateTime.Now;
attach.ContentDisposition.Inline = false;
attach.ContentDisposition.Size = bt.Length;

message.Attachments.Add(attach);
```

Comment: Open the bt[] -> disk and bt[] -> attachment -> disk files in a hex editor and see what different?

Comment: The message simply means excel doesn't recognize the format, when you click "Yes" it overrides the warning and attempts to format the content in the "Excel manner".  You may want to take a look at the formatting of openxmlformats again and ensure the content matches the spec. exactly.

Comment: @JohnPeters the question is, why I get this error only when I attach the file on an e-mail, but not when I create and open it "directly".

Comment: I can only guess at the answer because I don't know Excel internals and most of us don't...  Here's my thoughts, one of these options are not lining up.                                                                                  new MemoryStream(bt),
        "myfile.xlsx", 
        "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");   Just because a memory stream is said to be of a certain format, it doesn't make it that way.  One other note, Excel versions are radically different, it makes our job tougher to figure this stuff out.  They changed formats over the years

Comment: does this hold true if you send the email, save the attachment without opening it through your email client, and then open it?

Comment: You need a binary comparison, you may find writing to disk is adding a BOM for example

Comment: We (I and my collague) did all possible test and the conclusion is that there is something wrong when the file is attached to the e-mail. Maybe a missing header, or something else, I don't know exactly.

Answer (score 3):

Trying having the user save the excel document to their local machine and then open it. If errors still persist, instead of creating a .xlsx file from your code, just create a .xls and see if the same issue occurs.

If both methods above don't help, these two links may help

http://blogs.technet.com/b/emeaoffice/archive/2012/11/29/you-may-receive-quot-unreadable-content-quot-when-opening-files-from-within-excel-2007-if-you-have-a-shellstreams-dll-file.aspx

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/83907359-df5d-42ff-8f2b-a298e49adc61/error-quotexcel-found-unreadable-content-in-filenamexls-do-you-want-to-recover-the-contents-of?forum=excel

I don't think that this issue is related to your code at all. It seems like this is a common excel error that many people are getting.

Also, give [this](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5124) tool a whirl and see if it may help.

Comment: The tool mentioned above helped me http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5124