# excel found unreadable content, for the data stored through StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(@"Pee.xlsx", true)

Tags: c#, excel, streamwriter

When I write program output to an excel file through `StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(@"Pee.xlsx", true)` I get a blank spreadsheet and the following error message when I open the resulting file in Excel (*version?*):

> excel found unreadable content in 'Pee.xlsx'. Do you want to recover
>   the contents of this workbook?"

It gives me the right output when I open the same file with notepad or Word file but not with the Excel.

One year back everything was right. I did not have any problem in code or with Excel but I don't know what has happened now.

Comment: Is the spreadsheet in the same directory as your executable?  Because you don't specify the full path.  Check [Excel “found unreadable content” error opening a xlsx created from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27252845/719186) to see if anything there helps.

Comment: What is the expected output? Have you updated Excel, switched computers, or other changes to any moving part?

Comment: If you recover the contents, does it show correctly? Usually this sort of error relates to some problem in the underlying XML which Excel is able to repair, if you let it.

Comment: You are just writing **text files**, not actual XLSX Excel files (obviously, due to the fact that Notepad/Word -- two programs for working on text -- being able to open it). XLSX is not a text-based file format. No wonder Excel gets confused. Perhaps change the file extension to either .txt or .csv. This should indicate to Excel that the file in question is in some text format...

Comment: If you want to change the contents of an XLSX file it is often easier to use the Excel API to open the file in Excel, and then tell it what you want changed.
Here is a link to Microsoft to get you started: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/302084/how-to-automate-microsoft-excel-from-microsoft-visual-c-net